# Any new idea to force Windows 11 Explorer use classic context menu?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu, windows-11

In Windows 11 Explorer the context menu is changed to a new minimalistic one, however I like to use the more comprehensive old context menu as I put some customized entries there.

There were some registry tweaks to revert system to old context menu, but none of them works after the beta update. However I noticed that since I installed QTTabBar for tabs support, whenever I open Control Panel, the File Explorer window will close and reopen as classic Explorer. And if I create new tab from the reopened window, right-click will always show old context menu instead.

This behavior indicates that there should still be some way to force Explorer use old context menus. There's another registry tweak forcing classic Explorer that still works as of version 22000.100, but in that classic explorer the context menu is still the modern one.

Anyone get an idea on what to do?

Comment: Windows 11 is pre-release software that has its own feedback and support forum. Have you asked this question there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I revert to the old context menu in Windows 11?](https://superuser.com/questions/1674122/how-can-i-revert-to-the-old-context-menu-in-windows-11)

Answer (score 1):

[Explorer Patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) currently includes the options to use either Windows 11 context menus, Windows 10 (immersive) context menus or pre-Windows 10 (classic) context menus.

Answer (score 0):

> There were some registry tweaks to revert system to old context menu, but none of them work after the beta update

I've used the registry tweak from [this article](https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/07/16/get-the-old-right-click-context-menu-on-windows-11/) on Win 11 22H2, with the latest updates, and it still works for me.

Create the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\CLASSES\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32`. Right-click on the `(Default)` member in that key, choose `Modify...`, then explicitly set its value to nothing at all - which is *not* the same as the "`(value not set)`" that it starts off as.

Close Regedit, and reboot the PC. When it comes back up, you should get the full, old-style right-click menu by default.