# How can I revert to the old context menu in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

In Windows 11, right-clicking a file in File Explorer brings up a context different menu than in previous versions.

The new version is really great for people who want to pin everything to their Quick Access menu:

[image]

But if you want to do anything more useful than that, you'll need to click the bottom option to "Show More Options," which then brings up the "classic" context menu?

Is there any way to disable this so I can just get the normal context menu on the first click? I've followed the instructions [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-show-more-options-entry-from-windows-11-context-menu), but neither worked.

Comment: Cut, Copy, Rename and Delete are at the top -- I thought I'd point it out since it's [easy to miss](https://youtu.be/rfxepeL8Y54?t=18)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any new idea to force Windows 11 Explorer use classic context menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/1666756/any-new-idea-to-force-windows-11-explorer-use-classic-context-menu)

Answer (score 3):

[Explorer Patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher) currently includes the options to use either Windows 11 context menus, Windows 10 (immersive) context menus or pre-Windows 10 (classic) context menus.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Command Prompt and type this command do disable "show more options" :

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InprocServer32 /f /ve​
```

To enable it back :

```
reg delete HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2} /f
```

Answer (score 1):

The new context menu appears to be controlled by the following Registry Key:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}\InProcServer32
```

which on my machine is set to `C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.FileExplorer.dll`.

Note, I was unable to *modify* the above key, presumably due to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` portion of it. However, I was able to *override* it by using the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead. I just tested this on Windows 11 version 22000.493 and it worked:

1. Open Registry Editor: `regedit`
2. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\`
3. Create new key `{86ca1aa0-34aa-4e8b-a509-50c905bae2a2}`
4. Create new subkey `InProcServer32`
5. Edit the `(Default)` String value by changing it from "Empty" to a blank string.
6. Restart Explorer (via Task Manager->Processes, right click on Explorer->Restart), or just restart the machine.

Comment: I found this method at https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/07/16/get-the-old-right-click-context-menu-on-windows-11/ . Having tested it myself, I can confirm that it still works on Windows 11 22H2 with the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

This method may still work (although unknown for how long):

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
- Create a new item of type DWORD (32-bit) named `SeparateProcess`
  (if it doesn't already exist)
- Set its value to `1`
- Restart the computer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this registry file/code and restart your PC

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00



[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FeatureManagement\Overrides\4\586118283]

"EnabledState"=dword:00000001

"EnabledStateOptions"=dword:00000001

"Variant"=dword:00000000

"VariantPayload"=dword:00000000

"VariantPayloadKind"=dword:00000000
```

> Note: Before doing this you should backup the key you are modifying by
> either saving it as a reg file (Not recommended) or **By creating a
> system restore point(Recommended)**

Comment: Update (July 17): It is no longer working after updating to Windows 11 Insider preview 22000.71 update. Microsoft seems to have blocked the ways to get the old context menu. 
https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/07/16/get-the-old-right-click-context-menu-on-windows-11/

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the File Explorer. You can do it through the Start menu or by pressing Win + E.
2. Here, click on the three-dot menu at the top.
3. Select Options from the menu.
4. Once the dialog box appears, switch to the View tab.
5. Then, scroll down and enable Launch folder windows in a separate process under Advanced Settings.
6. Click on Apply and then OK.
7. Restart the computer even though it is not mandatory.
8. Right-click anywhere. You’ll see the old Windows 10-style context menu.

Comment: How is launching windows in a separate process related to the right-click menu?