# How can I start Notepad++ in Windows 11 using the new context menu?

Tags: notepad++, windows-11

Windows 11 is using a new context menu and while this is a good thing in most cases, it would be great to get access to a few chosen commands. For example Notepad++.

So luckily there is a workaround that I also found on superuser and here I will share it in the hopes to help others in my situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding custom commands on the windows 11 right click menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1711597/adding-custom-commands-on-the-windows-11-right-click-menu)

Answer (score 2):

Use this registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\pintohome]
"MUIVerb"="Edit with Notepad++"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\pintohome\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""
```

It uses this trick: [Adding custom commands on the windows 11 right click menu](https://superuser.com/q/1711597/168922)

Comment: This is really a hack! As specified in the reference link, a side-effect is that the "Pin to Quick access" will disappear from all context menus. I think this would deserve a clear warning in your answer here!

Comment: Specific solution for Notepad++: update to v8.5 where Windows' new context menu is now correctly handled. No hack needed